# how to avoid "duplicate class" in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have have a java project `myProject` and am using an external library jar (`someJar.jar`), which has a class `com.somepackage.Class1.class`.

Now I find an updated version of `Class1.java` which fixes a bug in the original jar.

I include the new `Class1.java` in my source code under package `com.somepackage`

When I build the project (e.g., using Netbeans), there is a `dist\myProject.jar` which contains the class`com.somepackage.Class1.class` and a `dist\lib\someJar.jar` which also contains a class with the same name.

When I run the file (e.g, using `java -jar dist\myProject.jar`), the new version of `Class1.class` is used (as I want).

1. How does Java decide which class file to run in case of such duplicates? Is there any way I can specify precedence ?
2. Is there any 'right' way to avoid such clashes?
3. In Proguard, when I try to compress my code, I get a `duplicate class` error. How do I eliminate this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Java decides which one to use based on the order of the classpath. List yours first and you'll be fine.
2. The "right" way would be to fix the orignal source, but sometimes that's not always an option.
3. I haven't used ProGuard, but I have re-jarred libaries before that had duplicate classes. The solution in my case was to tell Ant to ignore duplicate classes. I would assume ProGuard would have that support too.

Answer (score 6):

Can you not create an updated jar file which contains the bug fix? It's going to make things a lot simpler if you don't have two versions of the same fully-qualified class around.

Comment: I can do that. However, if in the future someone replaces that jar with an upgraded version (without the bugfix), the changes will be lost. I prefer to keep the java source code in the project to ensure that the bugfix is not lost. Is it possible to do it in a build tool? Note: the bug-fix is not part of the official release of the library and may not be part of the next one either.

Comment: @Jus12: You could certainly create an updated jar file as part of your build procedure, creating a copy of the jar file and then updating just that class. However, I'd say you've still got issues then - the class could *also* have been updated in the new version of the jar file, so that using the standalone bug-fix class file will cause problems. Is there any reason why the bug-fix *wouldn't* be part of the new version of the jar?

Comment: I am talking about the `smack` xmpp library and the bug-fix is the added support for `BOSH`. As of now, smack doesn't support BOSH and this hack is necessary to get it to work. Not sure why they don't support it yet.

Comment: Time and resources  8-(    You should just checkout the code, put your fix in and build your own own custom version of the jar.

Answer (score 1):

1) Updated Jar is a better solution.

2) Use a different class name. Is there a reason, why you want to use the same class name and same packing? I don't think there is a reason.

3) create a wrapper/ proxy class, that encapsulate all the calls to the jar and you can decide to call this new class that fixes the bug ( provided it has a different name and packaging)

Comment: If the class (with the bug in it) is instantiated by third-party code, you can't just provide a new, distinct class.

Comment: Yup, that is the reason I had to keep the same name.